# Conditional probability of Brownian bridge

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, brownian-bridge

Suppose $B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t)$ is a Brownian bridge such that $B_{0,a}^{T,b}(0)=a$ and $B_{0,a}^{T,b}(T) = b$. The probability density function of $B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t)$ is the conditional probability density function of the Brownian motion $B(t)$ given that $B(0)=a$ and $B(T)=b$. That is
$$ f_{B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t)}(x) = f_{B(t)}(x|B(0)=a,B(T)=b).$$
It is equivalent to
$$ \mathbb{P}(B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(B(t) \leq x |B(0)=a,B(T)=b).$$
I want to ask how to express this probability in term of $B(t)$
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \leq x \middle| \min_{s \in [0,T]} B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \geq y \right) ?$$
Is it equal to
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \leq x \middle| \min_{s \in [0,T]} B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \geq y \right)
=\mathbb{P}\left(B(t) \leq x \middle| B(0)=a,B(T)=b, \min_{s \in [0,T]} B(s) \geq y \right)
 ?$$
May I have some detailed explanation about it?

Comment: This is true, since conditioning on $A\cap B$ is equivalent to conditioning first only on $A$ and then further on $B$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it from the definition of Brownian bridge that $$ \mathbb{P}\left(B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \leq x \middle| \min_{s \in [0,T]} B_{0,a}^{T,b}(t) \geq y \right) =\mathbb{P}\left( \left[B(t) \leq x \middle| \min_{s \in [0,T]} B(t) \geq y \right] \middle| B(0)=a , B(T)=b \right)?$$

Comment: Yes, exactly.~~

Comment: May I find the fact about your first comment in somewhere?

Comment: When both events $A$ and $B$ are of positive probability, it always holds that $\forall C$, $\mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)=\mathbb{Q}(C|A)$, where $\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{P}(\cdot|B)$. You can check this directly using the definition of conditional probability. If either $A$ or $B$ is of probability $0$, then we need the definition of regular conditional probability. Again $\mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)=\mathbb{Q}(C|A)$ follows directly from the definition.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{P}(C|A \cap B)$ denoting $ \mathbb{P}(C|(A \cap B)) $?

Comment: Yes.~~~~~~~~~~~~